# Export JSON from quill to database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, quill

Good day dear community,

I'm trying to get the `JSON` of the Quill Rich Text Editor into a `MariaDB` database.

**JSON to form**

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function () {
var body = document.querySelector('input[name=body]');
body.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());
};
```

**From to PHP, to SQL**

```php
require "db_connection.php";
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $header = $_POST["header"];
    $body = $_POST["body"];
    $state = $_POST["state"];
    $worktime = $_POST["worktime"];
    $agent = $_POST["agent"];
    $creationDate = $_POST["creationDate"];
    $startDate = $_POST["startDate"];
    $endDate = $_POST["endDate"];
    $billed = $_POST["billed"];

    $sql = "UPDATE 
    `ticketsystem`.`ticket` 
SET 
    `header` = '$header', 
    `body` = '$body', 
    `state` = '$state', 
    `worktime` = '$worktime', 
    `agent` = '$agent', 
    `creationdate` = '$creationDate', 
    `startdate` = '$startDate', 
    `enddate` = '$endDate',
    `billed` = '$billed' 
WHERE 
    `ticket`.`id` = '$id';";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

**The JSON:**

```
{"ops":[{"attributes":{"bold":true},"insert":"Test Message"},{"insert":"\nThanks for reading.\n"}]}
```

If I insert this into the Database it looks like this:

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"asfggd
adsg
"}]}
```

So far I know the problem, but I find no solution ...